# TypeError when calling multidimensional NumPy array by index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, ipython

I could not make the code look normal...

```
import numpy as np

test = np.zeros(3,2)

print(test[0])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-35-81513f7c30bf> in <module>()

      1 import numpy as np

----> 2 test = np.zeros(3,2)

      3 print(test[0])

TypeError: data type not understood
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the shape a tuple:

```
test = np.zeros((3,2))
print(test[0])
```

Output:

```
[ 0.  0.]
```